# Automatic resizing of div for dynamic content

Tags: css

Im hoping someone can help me with a CSS problem. I'm using JavaScript to add additional rows to a table which is working fine however my page doesn't expand when I add new rows which means that the content becomes invisible as it disappears off the page.

Here is a simplified version of my webpage:

```
<div class="wrapper" >
  <section id="main" class="column">
     Expanding table code here.
  </section>
</div>
```

I also have the following CSS:

```
.wrapper {
width:1200px; 
overflow:hidden; 
margin:0 auto; 
border:1px solid #999;
border-bottom:2px solid #999;
}

section#main {
width: 77%;
min-height: 500px;
float: left;
margin-top: -2px;
}
```

I have tried adding overflow:hidden; to the CSS for the main section as I thought this might work but it didn't. If I remove the main section then it works fine but I need this because I have other content within my wrapper div.

Any help would be much appreciated as this is driving me mad!!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You want the browser window to get larger?

Comment: The simplified case works fine http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nhGnE/ please post a fiddle that exhibits the problem..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli,  Ah yes!  I am deleting my comment.

Answer (score 1):

*[EDIT: It was pointed out to me in the comments that the OP is already using a float clearing method. Leaving my answer here though in case it helps someone with a similar problem but no clearing css.]*

It's because you are floating `section#main`. Floated areas need a clearing div after them (or float-clearing css) because they don't actually take up vertical space themselves. You can do it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" >
  <section id="main" class="column">
     Expanding table code here.
  </section>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

The `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` is the traditional way to do it, but you may want to consider a new method described here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: The OP **is** doing one of the alternate methods.. setting the wrapper to `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Hi Ben Lee. Thanks for the tip and thanks also to the other posters! I must admit that im not great when it comes to CSS although I did try your clear:both solution but it didn't work for me. One solution I have found is to add overflow:auto; to the main section, the only problem with this is that it produces scroll a scroll bar for the new content rather than expanding the entire section. If you have any more suggestions, i'd happily give them a go. Thanks :)